# Changing innerHTML after calling getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the `innerHTML` of each `div`. I'm not seeing the code work as intended. Can anybody help me understand why the changes are not occurring?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="background: #FFEE05">f</div>
    <div style="background:#2B9423 ">d</div>
    <div style="background: #0024FF">s</div>
    <div style="background: #EF2E31">e</div>
    <script>
 var dvs=document.getElementsByTagName("div")
 dvs.innerHTML="<a href='#'>click here</a>"
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of dom objects. Every div on the page. You can't set the HTML of all of them like that.

Answer (score 3):

getElementsByTagName returns an array

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="background: #FFEE05">f</div>
    <div style="background:#2B9423 ">d</div>
    <div style="background: #0024FF">s</div>
    <div style="background: #EF2E31">e</div>
    <script>
 var dvs=document.getElementsByTagName("div")
 
 for(let i=0;i<dvs.length;i++){
 dvs[i].innerHTML="<a href='#'>click here</a>"
 }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank for you answer

Comment: in the future you should try to search for these answers first before posting a question. Accept the answer if it works for you.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` return an array of selected items, you need to iterate over it to assign value to individual element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="background: #FFEE05">f</div>
    <div style="background:#2B9423 ">d</div>
    <div style="background: #0024FF">s</div>
    <div style="background: #EF2E31">e</div>
    <script>
 var dvs=document.getElementsByTagName("div")
 for (let i = 0; i < dvs.length; i++) {
   dvs[i].innerHTML="<a href='#'>click here</a>"
 }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank for you answer its work for me

Comment: whats the let before i in for

Comment: let is used to create variables like var. Difference is we can create block scope variable using let keyword. please find reference here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: ok ! tnx a lot for your answer